# Problems importing csv to Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import the .csv file I downloaded from here:
https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SL.UEM.TOTL.ZS?type=shaded&view=map

Example:

| Country Name,"Country Code","Indicator Name","Indicator Code","1960","1961","1962","1963","1964","1965","1966","1967","1968","1969","1970","1971","1972","1973","1974","1975","1976","1977","1978","1979","1980","1981","1982","1983","1984","1985","1986","1987","1988","1989","1990","1991","1992","1993","1994","1995","1996","1997","1998","1999","2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2021","2022", |
| --- |
| -------- |
| Aruba,"ABW","Unemployment, total (% of total labor force) (modeled ILO estimate)","SL.UEM.TOTL.ZS","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","", |
|  |
| Africa Eastern and Southern,"AFE","Unemployment, total (% of total labor force) (modeled ILO estimate)","SL.UEM.TOTL.ZS","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","7.33333582862451","7.31874715974837","7.24270531831179","7.16069407881989","7.06379600929184","7.05599784776945","7.09054127946598","7.06009639229653","7.01527149574635","6.93953643462879","6.8503760036099","6.80353665561531","6.74124106047488","6.53517315091514","6.37350255682969","6.34759835935351","6.28342096946086","6.23256052686116","6.29558691357936","6.93364466215657","6.71535792804545","6.59935562174995","6.51278434882641","6.55564570993812","6.70714201994761","6.85558937799669","6.94036492503842","6.91304612233971","7.12166311855541","7.63130388835244","7.92021872219359","7.91683536433004", |
|  |

In Jupyter I have written this:

```
unemp = pd.read_csv("UnemploymentRate.csv")
print(unemp.columns)
```

I get the right values for the names of the columns, but if I then look at how the dataset is imported. I end up with the result in the attached image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9wVR.png)

I think the problem is due to the fact that all the values in the .csv have " " but I don't know how to fix that.

Thank you for any kind of help!

Comment: `read_csv` provides lots of parameters for fine-tuning, especially `sep` and `quoting` should be interesting for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just skip the first four rows:

```
data = pd.read_csv("unemployment.csv", skiprows=4)
print(data)
```

would output:

```
                    Country Name Country Code  ...       2022 Unnamed: 67
0                          Aruba          ABW  ...        NaN         NaN
1    Africa Eastern and Southern          AFE  ...   7.916835         NaN
2                    Afghanistan          AFG  ...        NaN         NaN
3     Africa Western and Central          AFW  ...   4.742175         NaN
4                         Angola          AGO  ...  10.209000         NaN
..                           ...          ...  ...        ...         ...
261                       Kosovo          XKX  ...        NaN         NaN
262                  Yemen, Rep.          YEM  ...  13.590000         NaN
263                 South Africa          ZAF  ...  29.806000         NaN
264                       Zambia          ZMB  ...   6.131000         NaN
265                     Zimbabwe          ZWE  ...   7.945000         NaN
```